# Ruby on Rails - Apply function to multiple fields using before_save callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

**Please be aware that this is an example, not my actual use case.  The underlying concept is what I'm after**

(Ruby version - 2.2.1, Rails version - 4.2.4)

Pretend I have `email` and `first_name` fields in my database and I want to downcase the using the before_save callback.  Normally, I'd do this

```
before_save :downcase_function

...

private 

def downcase_function
  self.email = email.downcase
  self.first_name = first_name.downcase
end
```

However, this isn't very flexible or reusable.  What if I want to add this function to the last_name field?  What if I need it across multiple models?

What I'd like to do is something like this

```
#pseudocode - does not work

before_save :downcase_function(:email, :first_name, :last_name)

...

private 

def downcase_function(fields)
  fields.each do |f|
    self.f = f.downcase
  end
end
```

I know this might look silly, but I'm having no luck.

**Here are the key things I'm after:**

- Create a function that runs before_save
- Allow this function to take arguments
- Apply the function to each field specified my the arguments
- (ideally) abstract it away from any one model so I can use it in any model, if needed

Thank so so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
ATTRS_TO_DOWNCASE = %i( email first_name last_name ) 
before_save :downcase_attrs

private 
def downcase_attrs
  ATTRS_TO_DOWNCASE.each do |attr|
    write_attribute(attr, read_attribute(attr).downcase)
  end
end
```

Comment: That seems solid!  I'll give that a go.  However, I'm pretty new to Rails in general, so would you say that your method is an good practice?  Just for curiosity :)

Comment: Using `read_attribute` and `write_attribute` might be more clear in intent.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you pass a proc to `before_save`, then call a function with arguments? Then you can extract the downcase function into its own module when and if you need to.

```
before_save {
  downcase_function(:email, :first_name, :last_name)
}

private 

def downcase_function(*fields)
  fields.each do |field|
    self.send "#{field}=", self.send(field).downcase
  end
end
```

Comment: `self.f` is not a method you can call. `:email.downcase` is likewise broken.

Comment: Right, sorry about that. This should work. I'm not sure if you must do symbol conversion though.